# No way to light a scene with selective lighting without using layers?

Tags: lighting

I am slowly switching to Blender from C4D, and so far, i am loving (specially the character animation part_

But I've been trying to find, for a very long time an easy way to light up a scene with selection/restrictive lighting (this light will only affect this cube, this other light will be only for the background, etc...) in Blender, but I coulddnt find a direct and straightforward way to to achieve this.

I only saw some options when using layers/composition etc.. which is quite combersome for something that could be so simple, in just one pass..?

Is there any other way to achieve this results?

Thanks in advance!